# 29 "User was removed" events, in two batches. What's going on?

Tags: support, reputation, achievements-dialog

Today tens of upvotes where removed from the reputation list at top of the website. First I saw 12 "-10 User was removed" lines. In about an hour I saw more of these lines.

I know there are similar questions here and I'm not asking what does this mean.

I wonder why did it happen twice per hour. And is it possible to know what users exactly caused this?

[image] [image]

In my profile, there is only one "removed" event listed:

> [image: -290 user was removed]

Comment: No, you can't find out who the users were (they're deleted anyway).  The event happened whenever a user was deleted, what else is there to say?

Comment: The user(s) don't exist any more so no more information about them. It seems to be a single user targeted you to upvote and that user was removed.

Comment: @PatrickHofman yes, I'm answering a lot in a small tag. But why did this happen twice with difference in one hour?

Comment: @PatrickHofman weird, in the user's [profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1227923/alexey-mezenin?tab=reputation) it appears as -290, so it's single user indeed, who upvoted 29 answers of the OP.

Comment: Maybe the serial voting script caught one occasion and a moderator discovered more and decided to remove that user entirely.

Comment: @ShadowWizard in `top users - last 30 days` of mentioned 'small tag' I can see two Indian guys dissapeared from the list few hours ago (never saw this before). So it's some kind of 'ring' of upvoters? Is there any information I can read about 'rings' here at SO?

Comment: @Pat serial voting reversal got its own reputation event, so that's not the case here.

Comment: Okay then. Maybe a user who asked to remove their profile then? And all votes go with him. Why in two steps I can't say then.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin might be those two were the same person, and accounts were merged and deleted, this can explain things. But still, we're all guessing here. Only SO moderator or SE staff can tell for sure what happened and why.

Comment: A mod-deleted voting ring is going under the serial vote reversal notice too?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I don't think there is serial voting here, those 29 upvotes were legit.

Comment: Okay. Then two user-requested profile deletions will do.

Comment: @Pat still, one "user removed" event in the profile page, so merge also took place. Weird. Anyway, that's not ordinary scenario, reopened.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm responsible for this. Two users were each operating sock puppets that voted for themselves and that they used to cast extra votes for people they liked. I deleted those sock puppets, who had each cast over 50 votes, at two different times. Turns out the two users were actually the same person, too, so those accounts were merged and extra votes they cast invalidated at that time.

A percentage of the votes these various puppets had cast went to others, so there will be some collateral vote invalidation due to their removal. If it's any consolation, you had never really earned those votes in the first place, since they all were multiple votes cast by the same person. This simply brings things back to how they should be.

Comment: But why the separate 29 "user removed" in the achievements dialog?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Could be an artifact of the way that the inbox works. In the reputation history, they are aggregated into a single event: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1227923/alexey-mezenin?tab=reputation . Same result.

Comment: hmm... maybe the achivements dialog show one for each post. Will have to dig deeper. Thanks!

Comment: The achievements dialog does show invalidated votes individually.  So does the reputation tab in the mobile web site.  I've seen that before.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I can see two guys were removed from `last 30 days top` yesterday - Amit Gupta and iCode. And today one new guy `pseudocode` appeared in the top. I wonder if you know the guy is cheating why did you merge his accounts instead of removing him completely?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin If you remove the account completely the vast majority of the history and evidence goes with it, so he can just come back with a "clean" slate and no evidence.

Comment: @ɥʇǝS I've had a conflict with the guy, he copied others' answers (without any changes), so he earned some rep on this. Then he cheated by using at least 3 accounts and when he got caught he lost like only 20% of the rep. Doesn't look fair to me. But maybe I don't understand something in SO policies.

Answer (score 10):

As an update to this, outside of Brad's answer:

We've corrected the achievements dialog so that it correctly aggregates "user was removed" and "serial voting was reversed" events into a single event, rather than displaying them all in a list like this. It should now match what is displayed in your reputation history<sup>*</sup>.

*<sup>*</sup> Kind of. Some specific events might get excluded from the achievements dialog, which could cause the total reported in the achievements dialog to differ slightly from the total reported in the reputation history. The total in the reputation history will always be the correct total, if they are different.*